# Failed to subscribe thenMany item

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

When I use `Mono.thenMany`, the Flux data is lost, why?

```
@Test
fun thenManyLostFluxDataTest() {
  Mono.empty<Int>()
    .thenMany<Int> { Flux.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2)) }
    .subscribe { println(it) } // why not output item 1, 2
}
```

If I change to use `blockLast()` to do the subscribe, the test method run forever. So fearful:

```
@Test
fun thenManyRunForeverTest() {
  Mono.empty<Int>()
    .thenMany<Int> { Flux.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2)) }
    .blockLast() // why run forever
}
```

Now I use another way to do what the `thenMany` method should do:

```
// this method output item 1, 2
@Test
fun flatMapIterableTest() {
  Mono.empty<Int>()
    .then(Mono.just(listOf(1, 2)))
    .flatMapIterable { it.asIterable() }
    .subscribe { println(it) } // output item 1, 2 correctly
}ed
```

Comment: Commit a [issue#1314](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1314) to reactor-core.

Answer (score 6):

You are using Kotlin's "lambda as a last parameter" short-form syntax. The thing is, if you look at the `thenMany` method signature, it doesn't accept a `Function`, but a `Publisher`.

So why is that lambda accepted, and what does it represent?

It seems to be in fact interpreted as a `Publisher` (as it has only 1 method, `subscribe(Subscriber)`)!

Replace the `{ }` with `( )` and everything will be back to normal.

Comment: Wonderfull answer. The original is so.